# Segmentation fault in my program

Tags: c, function, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void memory_allocate(int *ptr)
{
    ptr=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
}

int main()
{
    int *ptr1;
    memory_allocate(ptr1);
    *ptr1=12;
}
```

My code causes a segmentation fault. Can anybody explain why?

Comment: Note well: a C function call cannot change its arguments as they are passed by value, ie. copied.

Comment: Have you tried compiling the posted code, with the warnings enabled?  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Wconversion` )  This results in three warnings, two of which must be fixed. 1) parameter 'ptr' set but not used. 2) 'ptr1' is used uninitialized in function: `memory_allocate()`

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, is error prone, and makes the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: it is poor programming practice to include header files, those contents are not used in the code.  I.E. remove the statement: `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: the posted code contains a memory leak because the allocated memory is not passed to `free()` before exiting the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that, when the function sets `ptr`, the new pointer value isn't passed back to `ptr1`.

One way to make this work is by using a pointer to pointer:

```
void memory_allocate(int** ptr)
{
   (*ptr) = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
}

int main()
{
   int *ptr1;
   memory_allocate(&ptr1);
   *ptr1=12;
   /* TODO: free memory here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You assign to a local copy of `ptr` when allocating the memory.  This is not visible outside the memory_allocate  function.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters are always passed by value in C. Even if it seems like you are "passing a pointer to the function", you are actually passing the **value** of the pointer to the function (the value of the address stored inside the variable `ptr1`), and not the pointer itself.

So you can imagine that this works functionally similar to:

```
int main()
{
   int *ptr1;

   // pass the value of ptr1 to memory_allocate
   {
       var tmp = ptr1;

       // this doesn't change the original variable
       tmp = malloc(sizeof(int) * 100);
   }

   *ptr1 = 12;
}
```

This doesn't mean you cannot change the value stored at that address, because you can easily dereference the pointer inside the function, but it means that you can never change the value of the original variable, **unless you pass a pointer to the actual variable** to your function, like explained by @NPE above.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. does not have any memory leak
3. checks for errors when calling system functions
4. properly passes the address of the pointer so the sub function can change where the pointer points to.
5. documents why each header file is being included
6. properly initializes local variables

and now the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // perror()
#include <stdlib.h>  // malloc(), free(), exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

// prototypes
void memory_allocate(int **ptr);


void memory_allocate(int **ptr)
{
    *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
    if( !ptr )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}


int main( void )
{
    int *ptr1 = NULL;
    memory_allocate(&ptr1);
    *ptr1=12;
    free( ptr1 );
}
```